# Java JSON String to Objects

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I receive a JSON in the following format from pandas in a Spring Boot application:

```
{\"Ticker\":{\"0\":\"GGB\",\"1\":\"CRD-B\",\"2\":\"QIWI\",\"3\":\"VIPS\",\"4\":\"PRDO\",\"5\":\"VALE\",\"6\":\"TCS\",\"7\":\"LL\",\"8\":\"ETD\",\"9\":\"PRIM\",\"10\":\"SNDR\",\"11\":\"MDU\",\"12\":\"CMC\",\"13\":\"TX\",\"14\":\"FOXA\",\"15\":\"EBS\",\"16\":\"SAGE\"},\"Price\":{\"0\":4.38,\"1\":7.93,\"2\":8.3,\"3\":10.04,\"4\":10.54,\"5\":11.45,\"6\":12.82,\"7\":17.23,\"8\":24.06,\"9\":25.14,\"10\":25.76,\"11\":28.47,\"12\":35.07,\"13\":38.02,\"14\":38.99,\"15\":40.07,\"16\":40.9},\"total_multiplier\":{\"0\":1,\"1\":1,\"2\":1,\"3\":1,\"4\":2,\"5\":2,\"6\":1,\"7\":1,\"8\":2,\"9\":2,\"10\":2,\"11\":2,\"12\":1,\"13\":1,\"14\":2,\"15\":2,\"16\":2}}
```

Then I try to get data from that string, but the following

```java
String tickersList =
    Objects.requireNonNull(fastAPIService.localApiClient().get().uri("/finmine/").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block());

tickersList = tickersList.substring(1, tickersList.length() - 1);
JSONObject tickersObject = new JSONObject(tickersList);
JSONArray tickersArray = new JSONArray(tickersObject);
final int n = tickersArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    final JSONObject ticker = tickersArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(ticker.getString("Ticker"));
    System.out.println(ticker.getFloat("total_multiplier"));
}
```

Throws

> org.json.JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]

I subtract " from a String, as fastapi client sends me it as a string; I tried adding square brackets at the beginning and end of the string, but then it throws an error where the value ":" is missing at character 654

How should I read that JSON in a proper way if I want to create objects of the following class later on with it?

```java
public class Ticker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String Ticker;
    private Double Price;
    private Double total_multiplier;
}
```

Comment: Those escape characters are going to mess with your string.

Comment: First, the JSON string is invalid (but you can make it valid by replacing the backslash characters to empty string). Second, the JSON string doesn't contain any JSON array.

Comment: Also, the Price, Ticker and total_multipliers have to be java objects with string variables with names from 0 to 16.

Comment: I suspect the error is actually your own code which is buthering the JSON. Your first line is what does that. What you should do instead of marshalling to a `String` directly marshall to your `Ticker` or a `Map` but not to a String. IMHO you are solving a problem that isn't there but you created yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your responses, the problem was with an initial response from my python client, where I converted DataFrame into json, but it was not a valid JSON string, and sent it to Spring app, using this code:

```
return df.to_json()
```

I replaced it by the following code:

```
return json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii=False))
```

What changed the format of my response from the one in my question into this:

```
[{"Ticker":"GGB","Price":4.38,"total_multiplier":1},{"Ticker":"CRD-B","Price":7.93,"total_multiplier":1},{"Ticker":"SAGE","Price":40.9,"total_multiplier":2}]
```

After that the following code:

```
String tickersList = Objects.requireNonNull(fastAPIService.localApiClient().get().uri("/finmine/").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block());
JSONArray tickersArray = new JSONArray(tickersList);
final int n = tickersArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     final JSONObject ticker = tickersArray.getJSONObject(i);
     System.out.println(ticker.getString("Ticker"));
     System.out.println(ticker.getFloat("total_multiplier"));
 }
```

Started working and I am able to read all the data I need, thank you again for pointing out on an invalid JSON string format!